# Internet not working well on MBA, after switching network?

Tags: network, wifi, macbook-pro

Let's say that I turned on my MBAir at home; wifi networking works. Then I close the lid (MBA goes to sleep) and go to different place with different wifi network. When I change the wifi network (eq when I go to nearby coffee shop) something strange happens: from that point I can not reach most of the internet. Even when I come back home, the same problem exists! This is a summary of what I have found:

- DNS is working
- reseting DNS (using `com.apple.discoveryd.plist`) does not help
- `ping` is working
- `traceroute` works
- turning wireless off and on does not help (via `ifconfig`)
- however, I can not connect to port 80, for example, using `wget` results with "connection timed out".
- browsers doesn't work (obviously)
- this issue is not related to a target web site, this happens all the time.
- other devices in my network work fine, so its not a router issue.
- re-adding network doesn't help.

The *only* thing that helps is switching computer off and then back on; but this is not a solution for me.

Can any one recommend a solution, preferably in terminal (so I can issue the fix everytime when I experience it)?

I have MBA 2013 and Yosemite installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had Wireshark installed, and since I've removed it, everything works.